# Cannot edit files inside devcontainer container in vscode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, devcontainer

I successfully created a devcontainer image with `devcontainer build` command with cli. Now I want to use it to edit files inside the docker image so what I did was that I created new folder `.devcontainer` with below files.
`devcontainer.json`

```
{
    "name": "test docker",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile"
}
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM my-image:latest
USER myuser
RUN chown -R myuser:mygroup /workspace
WORKDIR /workspace
```

I tried to `reopen in container` in vscode and it started the environment but somehow in a differently set workdir.
Then I went to the right directory and tried to modify the files but it didn't let me modify it ( cannot save the file).
This is the Dockerfile that I used to build the image.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:1-3.11-bullseye
WORKDIR /workspace
RUN groupadd -r mygroup && useradd -r -g mygroup myuser
RUN chown -R myuser:mygroup /workspace
USER myuser
COPY . .
```

How can I fix this issue?